# how I can get text of selected item in list item in oracle forms?

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

List item involved List element and list item value.
my list item value is different from their text I want to know how I can get the selected item text.
(it same az combo box,i need the text of selected item)
plz help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure if there is an easier way, but this should work:

```
DECLARE
   l_count INTEGER;
   l_text VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
   l_count := GET_LIST_ELEMENT_COUNT('MY_LIST_ITEM');
   FOR i in 1..l_count LOOP
      IF GET_LIST_ELEMENT_VALUE('MY_LIST_ITEM',i) = :MY_LIST_ITEM THEN
         l_text := GET_LIST_ELEMENT_LABEL('MY_LIST_ITEM',i);
      END IF;
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Are u sure? this part  l_text := GET_ITEM_LIST_LABEL('MY_LIST_ITEM',l_count);
 just return same value